# No default repository defined

Tags: svn, trac, revision

How to set up links to the revision ?

I enter [revision_number], rRevision_number, and take an error:

```
No default repository defined
```

**I found a solution to the Internet**

1) give the name for the repository - "default"

2) create a folder (hooks) in trac project

3) create a file "post-commit" in /hooks

**post-commit** content:

```
trac-admin $ENV changeset added "default" $REV
```

But it still does not work. what could be wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Using Trac-1.0.1 I have multiple repositories one can see at http:////admin/versioncontrol/repository in the web interface (with TRAC_ADMIN permissions).

Then I set an alias called `(default)` to one of them (also on that admin page). That should be enough.

Maybe call a resync additionally.

Answer (score 0):

This is specified in [the documentation](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#ReposTracIni):

Basically the default project is the one with no name, so you just need to specify an alias with an empty name.  This can be done in trac.ini, via trac-admin, or the UI.  Here's the example from the Trac docs to set it via trac.ini:

```
[repositories]
project.dir = /var/repos/project
project.description = This is the ''main'' project repository.
project.type = svn
project.url = http://example.com/svn/project
project.hidden = true

lib.dir = /var/repos/lib
lib.description = This is the secondary library code.
lib.type = svn
lib.url = http://example.com/svn/lib

.alias = project    ### <<< THIS SPECIFIES THAT 'project' IS THE DEFAULT REPO
```

According to the docs: Alternatively, the name "(default)" can be used instead of the empty name.